# Easy way to pass all environment variables from file to a program on MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal

For now I am running program like this: `ENVVAR1=val1 ENVVAR2=val2 myprogram`
What I want is to keep environment variables in a file called `.env` like this:

```
ENVVAR1=val1
ENVVAR2=val2
```

Is there easy way to pass all variables from a file as environment variables to a program?

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell script to do this instead of the .env file

e.g. in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

export ENVVAR1=val1
export ENVVAR2=val2

myprogram
```